# How to set default user on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 gdm login screen

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gdm

It seems that Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 gdm login screen is not consistent when displaying the list of login usernames. Does it display the list of usernames by alpha sort, or by last logged-in username?

On my machine, the login screen shows my username at the top of the list, and highlighted, so all I have to do is hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type my password, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

On my sister's computer, her login screen seems to be an alpha sort, with her username appearing second in the list of usernames, not being highlighted, and requiring the use of the arrow keys to first select her username.

What's the default way of displaying the list of usernames? Are there gdm options that can be used to change that behaviour?

Comment: I would probably guess it sorts by numeric user id. The first user ever created gets UID 1000, the second 1001 and so on. Check yours with the `id` command.

Comment: @ByteCommander hum, good idea, but it doesn't look like it's done by UID, or by alpha. I'd like to think that it's done by last-logged-in-user. I'll have to keep poking around.